# Change Magento image size on search results page

Tags: magento, image-size

I have changed the size of the images on the category pages from 135px to 400px. It now shows 3 columns with 400px images. This works fine! BUT I want the search result page to look the same as the category page. It already has 3 columns and the images are displayed as 400px. The only problem is that it still loads a 135px small image. Now the images are very blurry. How do I change this so it will load a 400px image?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

By default Magento displays the search results through the template;

```
app/design/frontend/YOURPACKAGE/YOURTHEME/template/catalog/product/list.phtml
```

I you wanted to change that then the best thing you could do is follow the advice in the following link and designate a custom template to display your results by copying and renaming the list.phtml file;

[Magento design update to replace list.phtml on search results page only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14900291/magento-design-update-to-replace-list-phtml-on-search-results-page-only#answer-14900569)

You could then customise it however you want.  The section you would change is the following code which, as you can see ( the `->resize(135)` part) is resizing your small product image to 135px.  Change that to 400 and assuming the small image itself is not smaller than 400px wide then it want be pixellated.

```
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>
```

Answer (score -1):

This can only be done through CSS. The CSS depends on the theme your using.